# Text replacement in PDF document using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, pdf, adobe, adobe-indesign

I have some PDF templates that contain placeholders for things like a name, company, etc. They are in the format

<<'NAME'>> or <<'COMPANY'>>

Currently the process at my company is to replace all of these placeholders by hand when we get the information. I am trying to automate the process by getting the information from a CSV file and just doing a find and replace on the placeholders. However, the only files I have are inDesign files and PDF's for the templates. I looked at inDesign files, and as far as I can tell they are executable's and impossible to read in.

I was hoping someone knew of a way to read in a PDF file to do a regex on it to replace the placeholder text.

Comment: Look at this similar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220445/how-to-program-a-text-search-and-replace-in-pdf-files