# Substituting Names with new string (to anonymise) in multiple PDF based application forms

Tags: javascript, pdf, replace, substitution

I'm looking to find a tool or script that could take all instances of a person's first name and last name from a set of PDF based application forms and replace it with a randomly generated four-letter string.

Each PDF would have a different name (completed by a different person), but these could be found in the field, or at least are in the same place each time. This would serve to anonymise/blind applications for job applications. There will be multiple instances of each name through the file as references are included. The applicant names are also in the filenames.

I'll be looking to do this for hundreds of files. I could potentially have a file with the text to find and replace in columns but not sure how to achieve this.

I've seen this post on how to replace text in multiple files but it's less helpful for me having to replace specific instances of words in each file. [How to program a text search and replace in PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220445/how-to-program-a-text-search-and-replace-in-pdf-files)

Any pointers of posts, tools or scripts that may help would be very useful. Many thanks.
-Sarah

Comment: Comment to add that https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CAM-PDF/bin/changepagestring.pl looks like a great option for what I have in mind but I'm having problems running it. Have installed CAM::PDF but getting error: Could not open 'lib/CAM/PDF.pm': No such file or directory

Comment: I am pretty sure the suggested Perl script requires a proper *unix environment. Cygwin might do as well if you are on Windows.